# Numeric format in WPF and Telerik Report

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-reporting

In my system the items sold in two ways: as piece and kilo .. So I store the quantity in database in decimal type, The problem is when I print receipt .. when I add item that sold in piece the quantity showing in my receipt as 1.00

My question is how to print 1 instead of 1.00 in receipt if the item is sold as pieces, and print Ex: 1.5 if the item sold as kilo ?

Thanks in advance
Abdusalam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solve my issues by changing the format of quantity value : 0.##